# Heap size overflow issues with sound clips

Tags: android, memory-management, soundpool

I'm creating an Android app that involves multiple short sound clips. At the moment, I'm using `SoundPool` to load my sound clips once a 2nd activity is begun by the menu activity. The problem I seem to be having is that once this secondary activity begins, the loading of the sound clips causes multiple heap size overflows and then after a bit the activity actually loads (the emulator never gives an error or a force quit). Would using the `MediaPlayer` help me here and keep these heap size overflows from occuring?

Also, at the moment, the menu activity starts the 2nd activity waiting for a result (using the `startActivityForResult()` function). Does this mean that the menu activity is being held in memory as well as loading the 2nd activity into memory? If so, could I help my memory issues by calling `finish()` on the menu activity once the 2nd one is started (then restarting the menu activity when the user wishes to go back to the menu or would this bring up a whole new set of issues?)?

Comment: Perhaps somewhat a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119405/android-how-to-increase-heap-size-at-runtime/4631393#4631393 ?

Comment: Doesn't look at all like a duplicated of that Q

Comment: You can use multi SoundPool instances to prevent the heap size error. You can find more detail from http://stackoverflow.com/a/15331311/1124084

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, soundpool will keep all the sounds in memory. A single instance of media player would probably be all you need [see here](http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/2010/08/android-soundpool-vs-mediaplayer-focus-on-soundboards-and-memory-problems/). You should do this and your memory issues should go away without having to go to any extreme measures.

Comment: Thanks. It's really unfortunate the Android docs don't tease this out more.